# Generate one by one notifications under one title like Whatsapp

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push

Currently I am working on pushnotifications.
I wish to make notification like whatsapp.

It works for single notification perfectly.
When I get another notification from same ID then I wish to display both notification under one Icon and title (App Name).

I upload my code here.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";
WebService w = new WebService();
JSONArray msendsuccess;
SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String user_id/* , temp_id */;
int temp_id;
private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 237;
private static int value = 0;
Notification.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new Notification.InboxStyle();
public ArrayList<String> msg;

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(SENDER_ID);
}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    displayMessage(context, "Your device registered with GCM");
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    preferences.edit();
    editor = preferences.edit();
    user_id = preferences.getString("id", "");
    msendsuccess = w.sendNotification(registrationId, user_id);
    try {

        SharedPreferences.Editor pref = preferences.edit();
        pref.putString("registrationId", registrationId);
        pref.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));

}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    // For notification ID
    String id = intent.getExtras().getString("id");

    if (id.equals("")) {
        temp_id = 0;
    } else {
        temp_id = Integer.parseInt(id);
    }
    // temp_id = Integer.parseInt(id);
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message, temp_id);

}

@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
    System.out.println("Message is" + message);

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message, temp_id);
}

@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context,
            getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error, errorId));
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

private void generateNotification(Context context, String message, int id) {
    int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);

    builder.setSmallIcon(icon);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setGroup(title);
    builder.setContentIntent(
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, new Intent(
                    context, JobCardDetailsNotification.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                    .putExtra("id", id), 0));
    builder.setGroupSummary(true);
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
    inboxStyle.setSummaryText(value+"");
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        builder.setContentText(message);
        inboxStyle.addLine(message);
    }

    value++;
    builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
    nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this into your create notification code

```
builder.setGroup("groupkey")
builder.setGroupSummary(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. In my code I got notifications in group but next notifications are generated two times and old notifications are updated by the new one. This occur by updating the value of value variable. If I not update value variable then new notification overcome to old notification

Comment: If I've to maintain the data and arrange every time to achieve group notification behavior then how setGroup is help here.